# Swap keys between arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following simple array of objects:

```
var myObject1 = [
   {name: "value1", adddress: "545454545445"},
   {name: "value2", adddress: "323233223"},
   {name: "value3", adddress: "33232"},
];
```

I would like to change the keys of each of the objects to the values of this array:

```
const myObject = [
   ['aa', 'name'],
   ['bb', 'address']
];
```

How can I achieve this result?

```
[
   { aa: 'value1', bb: '54545455454' },
   { aa: 'value2', bb: '3232323233' },
   { aa: 'value3', bb: '33232' },
]
```

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to rename the keys of your object.

```js
const myObject1 = [
  { name: "value1", adddress: "545454545445" },
  { name: "value2", adddress: "323233223" },
  { name: "value3", adddress: "33232" },
];

const result = myObject1.map((item) => {
  return {
    aa: item.name,
    bb: item.adddress,
  };
});

// [
//   { aa: 'value1', bb: '545454545445' },
//   { aa: 'value2', bb: '323233223' },
//   { aa: 'value3', bb: '33232' },
// ]
```